# write window wise result on different file

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is it possible to write window wise result on different file. Means, I need to append time to file prefix or make time wise directory so that I can access particular window result without an additional filter. (as like `apache-spark`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you are using windowing in batch or streaming mode.

In the streaming mode, Cloud Dataflow Service doesn't support writing to files [at this time](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/faq#streaming-io-support). In this case, you'd want to use the BigQuery sink instead, where we do support per-window sharding.

Code example (see [Javadoc](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/BigQueryIO) for more details):

```
PCollection<TableRow> quotes = ...;
quotes.apply(Window.<TableRow>into(CalendarWindows.days(1)))
  .apply(BigQueryIO.Write
     .named("Write")
     .withSchema(schema)
     .to(new SerializableFunction<BoundedWindow, String>() {
       public String apply(BoundedWindow window) {
         // The cast below is safe because CalendarWindows.days(1) produces IntervalWindows.
         String dayString = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy_MM_dd")
              .withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)
              .print(((IntervalWindow) window).start());
         return "my-project:output.output_table_" + dayString;
       }
     }));
```

In the batch mode, `TextIO.Write` doesn't have a convenience method ready for such purpose, but you can implement something similar yourself without much trouble. For example, a way to accomplish this is via `Partition` transform, whose outputs are piped to separate `TextIO.Write` sinks.